# How to use reduce() method on for loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am trying to write a code that converts a Binary into string, i take solutions step by step, my first step is add charcodes then use fromCharcode, I don't know if this is possible but on this is my code:

```
function binaryAgent(str) {
  var x = str.split(' ').map(function (item) { // split with space
    return item.split(''); //split every character
  });
  var fg = [];

  for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) { 
    var f = x[i].reduce(function (toArray,item){
      debugger;
      var rightPattern = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]; // i want to create this array on every iteration
      var op = rightPattern.shift(); // on every iteration, shift a value from rightPattern, this is for binary pattern
      if(item=='1'){ // if item is 1,i think it doesn't matter if it's string or num, I care for 0 and 1 only, push the variable op, shifted from array
        return toArray.push(op); // push it on the initial value,
      }
    }, []); // []<-- initial array. 
    return x;
  }
}

binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111");
```

I checked this with debugger and I have observed that: ON every iteration, my rightPattern array is set to undefined again and reset, I also cannot use push and I have this error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

on MDN, there is an example using concat() method so i tried to push [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: you have to call reduce on the array. Then in the reduce function you return `toArray` on every iteration. Also `return toArray.push(op)` doesn't return toArray but op.

Comment: Indenting your code would be a good start.

Comment: i want to pass values 128,64,32... so i checked 1s and 0s on their respective place, I try to use shift, then push it on initial array, with values[128,2,1].. something like that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write your function like this:

```
function binaryAgent(encoded) {
  return encoded.split(' ').map(function(bytestr) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bytestr, 2));
  }).join('');
}
```

Converting binary representation into numbers is, well, an old task, and it's already solved for you. Even if you want to write your own implementation for studying purposes, it's better to abstract it (so that you can replace `parseInt(bytestr, 2)` line - but leave the rest of the code intact.

One possible reduce-using approach (not the most performant, mind you, but employing a pretty common technique):

```
function parseBinary(str) {
  return str.split('').reduce(function(acc, el) {
    return acc * 2 + +el;
  }, 0);
}
```

That is, you don't have any 'pre-filled' arrays of powers of 2; instead your accumulator is multiplied by 2 at each reducer step, adding the current digit. As `+` operator is overloaded, you should convert the digit operand into a number (the easiest way is applying unary plus - `+`).

---

Answering the question given in the comments: you can easily convert any number to binary, octal or hex format by calling `toString()` on it, with a passed argument treated as a radix. But here's a function for it:

```
function toBinary(num, reslen) {
  var res = '';
  while (num || res.length < reslen) {
    res = (num & 1) + res;
    num >>= 1;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: This saved my day! Thanks a lot, didn't expect it to be this short, it's great to see codes like this while learning, I think I am in the right place :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'd suggest checking [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) section of the MDN docpage, seems to be you're trying to solve a task already solved at the baremetal level. )

Comment: @raina77ow How can `65` be converted to `"01000001"`?

Comment: You mean other than `65..toString(2)`?

Comment: @raina77ow That approach is helpful and resolves why particular results were returned at `console` when trying different approaches to return expected result of Question; once gathered what value passed to `binaryAgent` was from your Answer. Are there other patterns or methods which return same conversion result?

Answer (score 0):

first of all - in your reduce function - if item wont be equal to one - in the next iteration toArray will be undefined.

you need to always return a value in the reduce function in order for the first argument (the accumulator) to be defined

should be something like that -

```
if (item == 1) {
    toArray.push(op);
}
return toArray;
```

other than that as I understand your code - the rightPattern var should be outside the reduce function but inside the for loop.